# Life in our Chatroom

Tags: discussion, chat

As [the Base Camp](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp) has very little activity, I think it is nice to post photos of nature once in a while.
I have started with one.

Maybe one of our regulars can post a photo tomorrow, or in a week, so we have ongoing activity which we enjoy.

If you have opinions on this or other topics about the chatroom or photos, please post an answer here.

Comment: good idea.  good first post, wish i inderstood dutch, but it was surprisingly easy to get the gist, maybe from long ago german?

Comment: @ab2, I posted a short English text version in the base camp.

Comment: Danke (plus 10  more meaningless characters!)